# ASP.NET Core 1.0 Operation was Canceled

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a web application where a user can log in. The implemented logic is using default logic mechanism in **ASP.NET Core**. Unfortunately I am encountering a strange behaviour - when I login and logout like 3-4 times I get "operation was canceled" exceptions when invoking any method from `UserManager` class i.e `FindByEmailAsync`, `GetUserAsync` and it can be fixed only by restarting the server. There is not much information in logs, this is the most important log:

> `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException`: Error -4081 ECANCELED operation canceled

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: This may be related to an open issue posted here: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1139.

Comment: That's pretty ambiguous question. What's the "default logic mechanism"? You have to clarify your question otherwise people won't be able to understand your exact issue/problem.

Comment: By default mechanism I mean this concept:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/identity.html
Not sure what should be clarified here.

Comment: Hey Man, Do you have any updates regarding your issue? I faced the same.